# Why inaccurate ''member for" info is shown in Stack Overflow

Tags: bug

My Stack Overflow profile says "member for 10 months". I asked questions around March 2013, for example on March 13, 2013. So according to current date, it's more than 12 months. Does anyone have any idea why the site still says 10 months?

Side note: I'm new to meta, the question is not actually about the way site works, if the question is irrelevant please comment below I'll remove it.

Comment: Could you link to the question you think if from March 2013. Is it [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285925/how-to-populate-a-gridview-dynamically-using-multiple-queries)? If so I know whats happened

Comment: "the question is not actually about the way site works" You're asking about your user profile, no?

Comment: @RichardTingle That's great! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your [earliest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285925/how-to-populate-a-gridview-dynamically-using-multiple-queries) was posted at the end of April 2013. That's 10 months (just under 11) alright.

The "mar 13" you see is the date it was last modified. In your case, it was edited by you on that date this year (just a little over a week ago).

Comment: This is what I though. Its a problem with the way recent dates are shown (as unclear as humanly possible)

Comment: @Richard Tingle: "as unclear as humanly possible" I feel bad for you.

Comment: Grumble grumble US date notation